# How to authenticate by using windows credentials in c# web application under form authenticate mode

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am developing an web application and the application must satisfy these requirement:

The application will need to support authentication to Active Directory and SQL membership provider. If the currently logged-in Window Account of Actor Window Account is already existed in database, system show homepage and NOT show login form. Otherwise, system shows login form for user enter username and password to login.

The problem here is: I can't get windows account (username/ password) and then base on that username, i will check against database to continue by show homepage or show login page. How can it get username and password?

Notice that in IIS, system is configured under **Form** authentication, **NOT** windows authentication.

web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

I tries some such as : `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. `Environment.Name`, ... but it doesn't work.

Could you please help?

Great thanks.

Comment: Thanks Terry. I tried but it not suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you the link..hope will help you
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication

Comment: Is there a way to do same in UWP Mobile apps?